# Next.js Fonts and CSS vars

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, fonts

I am trying to use the "next" way of adding fonts. However I feel like the way they explain it seems extremely complicated just to preload a font.

I tried to export a function creating the font and then using the variable tag to create a css var. This doesnt work, I have imported the font into my page.js file. Then I exported a const function creating the font with this variable;

```
import { Oxygen } from "next/font/google";

export const oxygen = Oxygen({
    display: 'swap',
    variable: '--font-oxygen',
    subsets: ['latin'],
})
```

Then tried to use it in the linked css style sheet setting the font family to the exact var using;

```
font-family: var(--font-oxygen);
```

I am trying to learn Nextjs and this is just putting me off. It wont work, I dont want to set the class name of my html attributes to the font class name either unless I am doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use the font's `font.variable` method, not the `font.className` method.

```
import { Oxygen } from 'next/font/google'
 
const oxygen = Oxygen({ 
    display: 'swap',
    variable: '--font-oxygen',
    subsets: ['latin'],
})
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={oxygen.variable}> // USE .variable, NOT .className
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

Now, you can add that variable to any css class:

```
.text {
  font-family: var(--font-oxygen);
}
```

**Note:** This works with app router, but I am unsure if it works for page router.

This should preload the font as well, which means that it does not flicker when the page loads.

Comment: That worked! I must have missed the change in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a font used in your entire application you can import the font in `index.js` (when using Pages Router) or in the `layout.js` in your `app` folder (when using App Router). You don't have to add it to your CSS.

Then add `classname={oxygen.className}`

For Pages Router example;

```
import { Oxygen } from 'next/font/google'
 
const oxygen = Oxygen({ 
    display: 'swap',
    variable: '--font-oxygen',
    subsets: ['latin'],
})
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={oxygen.className}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```